# How do I install higher version of gcc but not as default?

Tags: gcc

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS where the default C-compiler is 'gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609'.

Normally, I do not upgrade my C-compiler unless and until I am upgrading the entire OS or receive a notification to do so via Software Updates.

However, for my work testing the Perl 5 core distribution, I need to be able to evaluate other contributors' smoke test results run where the C-compiler is gcc-7.2.  Hence, I would like to install gcc-7.2 but NOT have it become my default C-compiler.  I would like to use it only when needed for one specific task.

At links like this:

[How do I install g++-7 on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863517/how-do-i-install-g-7-on-ubuntu?newreg=3872aea607654d4498d3c7a8d495c0cf)

... I find instructions for a direct upgrade to gcc-7.* but I do not really want to upgrade; I simply want an alternate installation.

Is it possible to do this?  If so, how?

Thank you very much.

Comment: thank you for testing!  sorry but I can't help, except suggest using a vm to do gcc7 testing/compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `gcc-7` from the `toolchain-r` PPA should **not** affect your default installation of `gcc` - it will install `/usr/bin/gcc-7` and all the supporting files, but will not symbolically link `/usr/bin/gcc` to it.

For example, given

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1 20160904
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc-7 --version
No command 'gcc-7' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gcc-6' from package 'gccgo-6' (main)
 Command 'gcc-5' from package 'gcc-5' (main)
 Command 'gcc-5' from package 'hardening-wrapper' (universe)
gcc-7: command not found
```

Then

```
$ apt-cache policy gcc-7
gcc-7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04
  Version table:
     7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

$ sudo apt install gcc-7
```

Results in

```
$ apt-cache policy gcc-7
gcc-7:
  Installed: 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04
  Candidate: 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04
  Version table:
 *** 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ gcc-7 --version
gcc-7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

but

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1 20160904
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: For the third command in your instructions above, I do not get the result indicated.   I get: `N: Unable to locate package gcc-7`.  What am I missing?

Comment: @JamesEKeenan did you actually add the [toolchain-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) to your system yet? and run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: You are correct.  I needed to perform some of the commands listed in the link cited earlier with yours.  This is the sequence I followed:
```$ sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences; sudo apt-get update; sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test; sudo apt-get update; apt-cache policy gcc-7; sudo apt install gcc-7```.  At that point, ```gcc --version``` and ```gcc-7 --version``` gave different results, as expected, and I was able to compile perl 5 blead by configuring with: ```sh ./Configure -des -Dusedevel -Dcc="gcc-7"```.